# flutter can't build APK with ProGuard

Tags: android, flutter, proguard

I just run `flutter build apk --release`
But build failed because of those warnings.
How can I fix these? 
Anyone has an idea?

> Warning: library class com.google.gson.Gson$6 extends or implements program class com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Priority
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.engine.impl.PicassoEngine: can't find referenced class com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Priority
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.internal.model.SelectedItemCollection: can't find referenced class com.zhihu.matisse.R$plurals
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.internal.model.SelectedItemCollection: can't find referenced class com.zhihu.matisse.R$plurals
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.internal.ui.BasePreviewActivity: can't find referenced field 'int error_over_original_size' in program class com.zhihu.matisse.R$string
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.internal.ui.BasePreviewActivity$2: can't find referenced field 'int error_over_original_count' in program class com.zhihu.matisse.R$string
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.ui.MatisseActivity: can't find referenced field 'int error_over_original_size' in program class com.zhihu.matisse.R$string
>   Warning: com.zhihu.matisse.ui.MatisseActivity: can't find referenced field 'int error_over_original_count' in program class com.zhihu.matisse.R$string

**ProGuard**

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

Comment: Do you have some native code with Picasso? Can you share your proguard file? Because it seems like it's a proguard issue.

Comment: Thank you for comment I edited. I just followed flutter web site instructions.

Comment: could you also share your build.gradle file? Do you have any native code implemented?